Book about a young man who joins his uncle's mercenary naval group
I read this book at least 20 years ago. It's set in the future. Nuclear weapons are banned, so conflicts are resolved by hiring mercenaries groups as proxies. Humanity lives in domed cities on the water.
The story revolves around a young man who joins his uncle's naval (as in actual water ships) group. The main plot revolves around a conflict they're hired for that puts them at odds with a few other groups.
The main action boils down to their mission to steal a massive battleship from one of the other groups and also to weed out a bad officer in their own group.

I believe you're looking for Surface Action by David Drake.
The only difference from your description is that the domed cities are under the water, in the depths of Venus' oceans, where they're safe from solar UV and predatory animals.
The protagonist is a young man named Johnnie Gordon who joins the fleet hired by his uncle.
All of the underwater cities are basically self-sufficient, which leads to them being mostly independent.  Unfortunately, this means that they come into conflict a lot, and that's where the mercenary fleets come in.
Johnnie's uncle believes that the situation is not stable long-term, since constant conflicts are endangering the cities; they need to be unified and he'll do it at gunpoint if necessary.
He has already pulled six (I believe) cities together into a single polity, and seeing the danger other factions have hired three fleets to oppose him.  His fleet is largest (36 ships or so) but the other three fleets together would be larger (I think the largest is about 20 ships) and hence pose a real threat.
The plan is for Johnnie to take a small party and steal the flagship of the smallest force, which they manage to do.  This leads to the rest of that fleet chasing them directly into the fire of the uncle's fleet, as the other two opposing fleets, uncoordinated, each fall in turn.

A spiritual sequel to Kuttner's Clash by Night, with a messy publication story: https://david-drake.com/2000/surface-action/ (Wish I'd seen this question a few hours earlier)
